# MAC address of bluetooth or wifi of an android device

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-bluetooth, mac-address

I am writing a program about the communication between android device and PC.

Is there any way to get the **MAC address** of BLUETOOTH or WiFi of an android device, when the Bluetooth or WiFi is turned **OFF**?

If so, how?

Comment: I have tried WifiManager, but it cannot get macaddress when it's turued off.

Comment: No. Same reason you can't get the license plate of a car that isn't there.

Comment: However, the MAC address is already burned in the phone's hardware when leaving the factory, isn't it? @MichaelPetrotta

Comment: My apologies. I'd thought you were asking how to discover the MAC address of a *remote* device.

Comment: I'd make it more clear, I want write a program in the android device to get the bluetooth or wifi's MAC address(turned off), any idea? @MichaelPetrotta

Comment: same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276380/how-to-get-mac-address-of-the-wifi-interface-in-android

Answer (score 1):

this works for me with wifi on and off i not try the bluetooth

```
WifiManager wimanager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
String address = wimanager.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
Log.d("TOKEN", address);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can get MAC addresses even when Bluetooth / WiFi is OFF.

Getting bluetooth information is as easy as this:

```
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getAddress(); // MAC address 
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().isEnabled(); // true if ON
```

No need to use `Context`, yay!

And to complete the answer.. WiFi state:

```
final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress(); // MAC address
wifiManager.getWifiState() == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED; // true if ON
```

Comment: Just important to note here that after Android M this returns `02:00:00:00:00:00`

Comment: Yes. They changed it due to security issues.