# How to get a Mac Address in an Android app built with Cordova 3.1

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3

Just wondering if anyone had any information on how to get the WiFi Mac Address in a Cordova 3.1.0 app?

I understand iOS7 doesn't let you, but I really need this for Android (although iOS6 wouldn't hurt either).

I am a n00b in terms of Cordova so would prefer to have a plugin that can be installed from the command line via "cordova plugin add ...." because I have found this to be the safest.

I have come across an iOS6 plugin (does not install from the command line), but really need an Android equivalent.

I've searched SO (and Google) and have not come up with anything that has worked.

Thanks in advance for any help or pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go ahead and write your own cordova plugin for android. Here is a post which tells you how to write your own plugin.

http://devgirl.org/2013/09/17/how-to-write-a-phonegap-3-0-plugin-for-android/

To find MAC address on android, May be you can follow this post.

[How to get MAC address of the WIFI interface in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276380/how-to-get-mac-address-of-the-wifi-interface-in-android/6276396#6276396)

Comment: as the other post states, access to hardware id is removed in Android 6 http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id